# Explain Artist Credit Name in MusicBrainz Schema

Tags: musicbrainz

Can anyone please explain the tables "artist_credit_name" and "artist_credit" in MusicBrainz Database Schema here http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/-/images/5/52/ngs.png?

What is the foreign key "position" in "artist_credit_name"? and which table does it relate to?
Can you explain the attributes in each table? I understand 'join_phrase' but why have two tables?

```
[artist_credit_name]
artist_credit (PK, FK)
position (PK)
artist (FK)
name
join_phrase

[artist_credit]
id
name
artist_count
ref_count
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you're referring to the lastest version of MB's db schema. If I'm correct, it has been updated since.

From what I remember `artist credit` and `artist_credit_name` tables are used to link `release_group` to `artist`. You can join these tables like that: `artist_credit_name.artist_credit = artist_credit.id = release_group.artist_credit`.

Here id what I created on a piece of paper 2 years ago, I'm pretty sure this part of the schema didn't change, so it might help (don't pay attention to "X" and "/" signs, that's personal notes).

[image: MusicBRainz Handwritten DB Schema from 2013]